# Calculate the standard oxidation potential from given potentials

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

> The standard electrode potentials for the following redox couples are given as: >$E_0(\ce{Fe^{2+}/Fe}) = x~\mathrm{V}$ and $ E_0(\ce{Fe^{3+}/Fe^{2+}}) = y~\mathrm{V}$
>   What will be potential $E_0(\ce{Fe^{3+}/Fe})$ (in $\mathrm{V}$)?

**My approach:** $\ce{Fe^{3+} + e- + Fe^{2+} + 2e- -> Fe^{2+} + Fe}$

So $E_0(\ce{Fe^{3+}/Fe})=(x+y)~\mathrm{V}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write down the three half reactions:

\begin{aligned}
 \ce{Fe^{2+} + 2e- &-> Fe}      & E_1&= x\,\mathrm{V}\\
 \ce{Fe^{3+} + e-  &-> Fe^{2+}} & E_2&= y\,\mathrm{V}\\
 \ce{Fe^{3+} + 3e- &-> Fe}      & E_3&= z\,\mathrm{V}
\end{aligned}

The third half-reaction is simply the sum of the first two. However, we cannot just sum $E_1 + E_2$ in order to obtain $E_3$. The problem is with the meaning of the potentials, and their relation to the stoichiometry.

An half reaction with potential $E$ in volts means that the elecrons have some energy assigned to them. The meaning of *volts* is *joules per coulomb*. The charge of one mole of electrons is 96500 C (this is Faraday's constant: 1 F = 95600C/mol).

Take a look at the first half reaction. It transfers two moles of electron per mole of reaction. This means the electrons carry

- $x$ joules per coulomb, or
- $96500x$ joules per mole of electrons, or
- $2\times 96500x$ joules per mole of reaction.

In the same fashion, the second half reaction has the electrons carrying

- $y$ joules per coulomb,
- $96500y$ joules per mole of electrons,
- the same $96500y$ joules per mole of reaction.

The third half reaction is the sum of the first two, so its electrons carry

- $2\times 96500x + 96500y$ joules per mole of reaction, which is
- $3\times 96500 z$ joules per mole of reaction, or
- $96500z$ joules per mole of electrons, or
- $z$ joules per coulomb.

Now you can simplify this to $2x + y = 3z$ and calculate the potential you want.

Comment: You should add that Electrode potentials of two reactions cannot be added because they are not state functions, i.e. dependent on the path. On the other hand $\ce{\Delta G}$ i.e. the energy carried by electrons, is a state function, and can be added.

Answer (score 4):

As correct as eflaschuks approach is, I found it rather confusing, because much text and few mathematics. So I am adding them here.

First of all, let us write down the Nernst Equation for an arbitrary reaction $\ce{Ox + z\cdot e- <=> Red}$:
\begin{aligned}
  E=E^\ominus(\ce{Red/Ox}) - z^{-1}\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Red}}{\ce{Ox}}
\end{aligned}

For our given system that boils down to the following reaction and their potentials:
\begin{aligned}
  \ce{Fe^{2+} + $2\cdot$ e- &-> Fe}& E_1 &= E^\ominus(\ce{Fe/Fe^{2+}}) - \frac12\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe}}{\ce{Fe^{2+}}}& \text{(1)}\\
  \ce{Fe^{3+} + $1\cdot$ e- &-> Fe^{2+}}& E_2 &= E^\ominus(\ce{Fe^{2+}/Fe^{3+}}) - \frac11\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe^{2+}}}{\ce{Fe^{3+}}}& \text{(2)}\\
  \ce{Fe^{3+} + $3\cdot$ e- &-> Fe}& E_3 &= E^\ominus(\ce{Fe/Fe^{3+}}) - \frac13\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe}}{\ce{Fe^{3+}}}& \text{(3)}\\
\end{aligned}

Now you are looking for the standard potential $E^\ominus(\ce{Fe/Fe^{3+}})$, so you have to consider the potential $E_3$, which can be build from $E_1$ and $E_2$:
$$E_3 = a\cdot E_1 + b\cdot E_2$$

Substituting $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields:

$$\begin{multline}
E^\ominus(\ce{Fe/Fe^{3+}}) - \frac13\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe}}{\ce{Fe^{3+}}} = \\
a\cdot\left(E^\ominus(\ce{Fe/Fe^{2+}}) - \frac12\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe}}{\ce{Fe^{2+}}}\right) \\+
b\cdot\left(E^\ominus(\ce{Fe^{2+}/Fe^{3+}}) - \frac11\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe^{2+}}}{\ce{Fe^{3+}}}\right)
\end{multline}$$

In order to obtain the standard potential the logarithmic terms have to cancel. Therfore we can split these equations:
\begin{aligned}
&&E^\ominus(\ce{Fe/Fe^{3+}}) &= 
a\cdot E^\ominus(\ce{Fe/Fe^{2+}}) +
b\cdot E^\ominus(\ce{Fe^{2+}/Fe^{3+}}) \\
&&\frac13\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe}}{\ce{Fe^{3+}}} &= 
a\cdot\left(\frac12\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe}}{\ce{Fe^{2+}}}\right) +
b\cdot\left(\frac11\cdot \mathcal{R}T\mathrm{F}^{-1} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe^{2+}}}{\ce{Fe^{3+}}}\right)\\
\therefore&& \ln\frac{\ce{Fe}}{\ce{Fe^{3+}}} &= 
\frac{3a}{2} \ln\frac{\ce{Fe}}{\ce{Fe^{2+}}} +
      3b     \ln\frac{\ce{Fe^{2+}}}{\ce{Fe^{3+}}}
\end{aligned}

In order for the $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ terms to cancel it is fairly obvious, that $$a=\frac23,\\ b=\frac13,$$ therfore resulting in 
\begin{aligned}
&&E^\ominus(\ce{Fe/Fe^{3+}}) &= 
\frac{2}{3}\cdot E^\ominus(\ce{Fe/Fe^{2+}}) +
\frac{1}{3}\cdot E^\ominus(\ce{Fe^{2+}/Fe^{3+}}).
\end{aligned}

You can also check that against experimental data (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_%28data_page%29)):
\begin{array}{llrlr}\hline
\text{halfreaction} &&&& \text{potential}\\\hline
  \ce{Fe^{2+} + $2\cdot$ e- &-> Fe}     & E_1 &=& -0.44\mathrm{V} \\
  \ce{Fe^{3+} + $1\cdot$ e- &-> Fe^{2+}}& E_2 &=& 0.77\mathrm{V}\\
  \ce{Fe^{3+} + $3\cdot$ e- &-> Fe}     & E_3 &=& -0.04\mathrm{V}\\\hline
\end{array}

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is a correct one.

Explanation: (I call the given two reduction half cell reactions as 1 and 2 respectively)

The required half cell reaction $\ce{Fe^{3+} -> Fe}$ could be obtained by adding reaction 1 and 2 .Thus the net $\ce{E0}$ value would be the sum of $\ce{E0}$ values of reaction 1 and 2 (as both are reduction half cell reactions.)

Hence net $\ce{E0(Fe^{3+}/Fe^{2+})} = (x + y) \, \text{V}$

Comment: Are you sure? I am quite sceptical about my approach.

Comment: Why should not the standard half reaction potentials for $\ce{Fe^{3+} -> Fe^0}$ be $\frac{2x+y}{3}$, as per calculating potentials between oxidation numbers in a Latimer diagram?